# jQuery ajax loaded elements, adding events to them automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

My website uses ajax and hashtags for every part of the navigation, so every element, (except for the main navigational parts) are loaded via ajax, which breaks the DOM connections to any elements inside of those (or whatever exactly happens), so I can't just have something like this in my javascirpt and it work for everything:

```
$(".chat-wrapper li").draggable();
```

currently I have to put this in the success part of my ajax call so when the chat buttons are loaded it adds this to them, and this is not my only instance of this being a problem, it happens for many things, this is just my current example, so my question is that does jquery or anything have a way of getting around this? There must be some method of doing this, so any element called in after the initial page load also works with these and all.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to bind an event to an element and have it persist, you can look into the jQuery function `.live()`.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Edit: After a quick look, it would appear that `.on` for jQuery 1.7+ (http://api.jquery.com/on/) and `.delegate()` (http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for jQuery 1.4.3+ would be better solutions. Usage examples for each function exists on the page links, but you can probably use it this way (I may be wrong as I just quickly typed it up):

```
$(".chat-wrapper").delegate("li", "bind", function() {
    this.draggable();
});
```

Alternatively:

```
$(".chat-wrapper li").on("bind", function() {
    this.draggable();
});
```

Comment: well I use on() for other things, maybe this is a silly question, but how would I use on/live with .draggable()?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not having any luck with either of those.